# Redux Middleware Infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux

On the snippet of code below I am having a hard time understanding how `result = next(action)` doesn't end up being an infinite loop. Since the "last function" `action =>` takes parameter `action` and calculates the `result` value based on the function that takes the `next` argument (`next => action =>`) that then call the function that takes the `action` parameter (`next => action =>`) AGAIN.

Essentially the recursiveness of this code is hard to understand.

```
import C from '../constants'
import appReducer from './reducers'
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'

const consoleMessages = store => next => action => {

    let result

    console.groupCollapsed(`dispatching action => ${action.type}`)
    console.log('ski days', store.getState().allSkiDays.length)
    result = next(action)

    let { allSkiDays, goal, errors, resortNames } = store.getState()

    console.log(`

        ski days: ${allSkiDays.length}
        goal: ${goal}
        fetching: ${resortNames.fetching}
        suggestions: ${resortNames.suggestions}
        errors: ${errors.length}

    `)

    console.groupEnd()

    return result

}

export default (initialState={}) => {
    return applyMiddleware(consoleMessages)(createStore)(appReducer, initialState)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`next` is not the name of one of *your* functions, it's the parameter name.

Calling `next` doesn't call the `action => {...}` function.

There isn't any recursion here.

Rewriting the code may clarify things for you:

```
function consoleMessages(store) {
  return function (next) {
    return function (action) {
      ...
      let result = next(action)
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. So when an "action" happens then it triggers the entire thing.  what is the next "object" then doing when you give it the action? is the console message trying to display the action that is happening now ?

Comment: is the reason to add the action => {..} function  is having the ability to do an asynchronous function? Since you could argue "result = next (action)" could be implemented in a function that accepts both the next & action object. Not sure why the last function is necessary.

Comment: "what is the next 'object' then doing when you give it the action?" `next` is a function. I don't know what it does. Feel free to look it up in the `applyMiddleware` API.

Comment: "is the reason to add the action => {..} function is having the ability to do an asynchronous function?" I don't exactly understand what you're trying to ask here. I think what you're not understanding is that the `applyMiddleware` function requires a parameter that behaves in a certain way. The reason for the behavior is entirely on the `applyMiddleware` function, so my recommendation is that you go review the source if you want to understand how it works.